# Running Multiple MySQL Queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP I'm attempting to build a form that needs to check for an ID in one table and if it exists it should create a record in another table. So far, that works but the issue I'm having is when I attempt to handle the case if the ID I checked for didn't exist. If it doesn't exist I'd like to create another one. But every time I try it, I get 500 errors from the server when I fetch the results.

Essentially I made the following function

```
function trySQL($con, $query, $params) {
$stmt = $con->prepare($query); 
$result = $stmt->execute($params); 
$id = $stmt->insert_id;
return array($stmt,$result,$id);
}
```

I call this function multiple times through out my php code but when I call it more then once and attempt to fetch the results it breaks.

```
   $custINSquery = "
        INSERT INTO custs ( 
            FirstName, 
            LastName, 
            EmailAddress, 
            PhoneNumber 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :FirstName, 
            :LastName, 
            :EmailAddress, 
            :PhoneNumber
        )
    ";

    $createJob = " 
        INSERT INTO jobs ( 
            custs_id,
            StAddress, 
            State, 
            ZipCode,
            MoistureLocation,
            status_id
        ) VALUES ( 
            :custs_id, 
            :StAddress, 
            :State, 
            :ZipCode,
            :IssueDesc,
            :status_id
        ) 
    "; 

    $custSELquery = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress FROM custs WHERE FirstName = :FirstName AND LastName = :LastName AND EmailAddress = :EmailAddress";

    $custSELquery_params = array( 
        ':FirstName' => $_POST['FirstName'],
        ':LastName' => $_POST['LastName'],
        ':EmailAddress' => $_POST['EmailAddress']
    ); 

    $checkcust = trySQL($db, $custSELquery, $custSELquery_params);

    $row = $checkcust[0]->fetch(); 

    if(!$row){
        $custINSquery_params = array( 
            ':FirstName' => $_POST['FirstName'],
            ':LastName' => $_POST['LastName'],
            ':EmailAddress' => $_POST['EmailAddress'],
            ':PhoneNumber' => $_POST['PhoneNumber']
        ); 

        $custins = trySQL($db, $custINSquery, $custINSquery_params);
        $custsel = trySQL($db, $custSELquery, $custSELquery_params);

        $custs_id = $custsel[0]->fetch();
        if ($custs_id != null) {
            $createJobParam = array( 
            ':custs_id' => $custs_id,
            ':StAddress' => $_POST['StAddress'],
            ':State' => $_POST['State'],
            ':ZipCode' => $_POST['ZipCode'],
            ':IssueDesc' => $_POST['MoistureLocation'],
            ':status_id' => $_POST['status_id']
            ); 
            $jobins = trySQL($db, $createJob, $createJobParam);
            $jobres = $jobins[0]->fetch();
            die("um...");
            if ($jobres) {
                # code...
                die("looks like I made it");
            }
        }

    } else {
        $createJobParam = array( 
        ':custs_id' => $row['id'],
        ':StAddress' => $_POST['StAddress'],
        ':State' => $_POST['State'],
        ':ZipCode' => $_POST['ZipCode'],
        ':IssueDesc' => $_POST['MoistureLocation'],
        ':status_id' => $_POST['status_id']
        ); 
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';            
    }
```

Additional Notes: When I look through the php doc's they are saying that I could use the inserted_id thing in order to get the ID that I inserted previously but when I try that it just gives me nulls with this set up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `$result["cust_id"]` or  `$stmt->lastInsertID()` or  `$stmt->lastInsertID('cust_id')` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, lastInsertID gives me a 500 error, and the other one just returned null values.@ShiguriAnemone'

Comment: If you are getting 500 errors, you need to actually look at the error logs and see exactly what error PHP is returning.

Comment: @jbafford oh man, I feel really dumb now lol. been a long time since I've had to dive back into php. thanks for the tip I think this will set me on the right path.